# FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "mobile" at /accounts to your security rules for better performance

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm facing this issue while fetching data from Firebase:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "mobile" at /accounts to your security rules for better performance
```

---

```
 var ref = new Firebase("https://lxxxxxxx-c7797.firebaseio.com/accounts");
                    ref.orderByChild("mobile").equalTo($scope.mobile).on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
                        //console.log(snapshot.key());
                        $scope.nodeId = snapshot.key();
                        $scope.name = snapshot.val().name;
                        $scope.mobile = snapshot.val().mobile;

                    });
```

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data